# AWS Glue job running out of memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I am trying to run an AWS Glue job (of type `G.1X` that has 15 workers). This glue job should generate a spark dataframe with the following schema:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+------------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|client_id_x|client_id_y|   dist|              time|      date|   lat_x|   lng_x|   lat_y|   lng_y|
+-----------+-----------+-------+------------------+----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| 7120061434| 7120110123|84899.3| 70.67166666666667|2021-08-19|-23.6595|-52.6062|-23.7626|-53.3129|
| 7120061434| 7120094771|18679.8| 19.68166666666667|2021-08-19|-23.6595|-52.6062|-23.5373| -52.585|
```

Locally I can generate up to 1 million rows. I expected to generate more with AWS Glue, however, I'm not even able to generate 600k. The Glue job shows the following errors:

```
Driver logs

Aug 22, 2021, 6:04:36 PM Pending execution
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:50 PM 21/08/22 23:05:50 WARN ApacheUtils: NoSuchMethodException was thrown when disabling normalizeUri. This indicates you are using an old version (< 4.5.8) of Apache http client. It is recommended to use http client version >= 4.5.9 to avoid the breaking change introduced in apache client 4.5.7 and the latency in exception handling. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919 for more information
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:54 PM 21/08/22 23:05:54 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 37887.
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:55 PM 21/08/22 23:05:55 INFO GlueContext: GlueMetrics configured and enabled
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:58 PM 21/08/22 23:05:58 INFO GlueContext: getCatalogSource: catalogId: null, nameSpace: cia_clients, tableName: clients, isRegisteredWithLF: false, isGoverned: false, isRowFilterEnabled: falseuseAdvancedFiltering: false
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:58 PM 21/08/22 23:05:58 INFO GlueContext: getCatalogSource: transactionId: <not-specified> asOfTime: <not-specified> catalogPartitionIndexPredicate: <not-specified>
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:58 PM 21/08/22 23:05:58 INFO GlueContext: classification parquet
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:58 PM 21/08/22 23:05:58 INFO GlueContext: No of partitions from catalog are 0. consider catalogPartitionPredicate to reduce the number of partitions to scan through
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:58 PM 21/08/22 23:05:58 INFO GlueContext: Glue secret manager integration: secretId is not provided.
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:59 PM 21/08/22 23:05:59 WARN EC2MetadataUtils: Unable to retrieve the requested metadata (/latest/user-data/). The requested metadata is not found at http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/
Aug 22, 2021, 6:05:59 PM 21/08/22 23:05:59 ERROR UserData: Error encountered while try to get user data
Aug 22, 2021, 6:06:01 PM 21/08/22 23:06:01 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (resolveRelation at DataSource.scala:720) with 1 output partitions
Aug 22, 2021, 6:06:16 PM 21/08/22 23:06:16 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
Aug 22, 2021, 6:06:31 PM 21/08/22 23:06:31 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
Aug 22, 2021, 6:06:46 PM 21/08/22 23:06:46 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:01 PM 21/08/22 23:07:01 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:10 PM 21/08/22 23:07:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: resolveRelation at DataSource.scala:720, took 69.248217 s
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:29 PM 21/08/22 23:07:29 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: run at ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149, took 15.215954 s
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:30 PM 21/08/22 23:07:30 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) with 1 output partitions
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:35 PM 21/08/22 23:07:35 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 647, 172.35.108.199, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main process() File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 286, in dump_stream for series in iterator: File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda> File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 113, in wrapped result = f(pd.concat(value_series, axis=1)) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/tmp/test3", line 116, in osrm_map File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 INFO DAGScheduler: ShuffleMapStage 11 (count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0) failed in 6.809 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 735, 172.35.108.199, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main process() File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 286, in dump_stream for series in iterator: File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda> File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 113, in wrapped result = f(pd.concat(value_series, axis=1)) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/tmp/test3", line 116, in osrm_map File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Driver stacktrace:
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 2 failed: count at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0, took 8.620489 s
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 4.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 736, 172.35.108.199, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 ERROR ProcessLauncher: Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last): File "/tmp/test3", line 163, in <module> print(cost_matrix.count()) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 522, in count return int(self._jdf.count()) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__ answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco return f(*a, **kw) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value format(target_id, ".", name), value) py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o149.count. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 11.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 735, 172.35.108.199, executor 4): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main process() File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 286, in dump_stream for series in iterator: File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda> File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 113, in wrapped result = f(pd.concat(value_series, axis=1)) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/tmp/test3", line 116, in osrm_map File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1889) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1877) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1876) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1876) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2110) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2059) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2048) at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2830) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$count$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2829) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$53.apply(Dataset.scala:3364) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3363) at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.count(Dataset.scala:2829) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main process() File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 286, in dump_stream for series in iterator: File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda> File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 113, in wrapped result = f(pd.concat(value_series, axis=1)) File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper return f(*args, **kwargs) File "/tmp/test3", line 116, in osrm_map File "/home/spark/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end()) File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:172) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.ArrowPythonRunner$$anon$1.read(ArrowPythonRunner.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406) at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey_0$(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage19.processNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636) at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409) at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ... 1 more
Aug 22, 2021, 6:07:38 PM 21/08/22 23:07:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 11.0 (TID 737, 172.35.108.199, executor 4): TaskKilled (Stage cancelled)
```

Certain lines caught my attention. There are some lines showing this error:

> WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118572/initial-job-has-not-accepted-any-resources-check-your-cluster-ui-to-ensure-that), it is caused due to the cluster has insufficient resources (because the workers were not started).

I have not found a concrete answer to solve this issue on AWS Glue.

Comment: What is the average file size and total number of files in source?

Comment: At the moment my final spark dataframe should have 640,000 rows. With a dataframe of 490,000 rows seems to work fine, but with 640,000 I always get the error above.

Comment: can you update your question with script?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an ETL task that would not complete because it was too much. I found out that I could adjust my configuration from the documentation at this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-to-scale-apache-spark-jobs-and-partition-data-with-aws-glue/

In my case I could change the type of the worker to make my task finish without throwing exceptions about too little RAM for my Spark task.

There were other answers and comments that one should explicitly set a configuration key-value to the glue job, but that would not work for me nor would it scale up with the scaling of the worker.