# running a spark driver on the GCP VM

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use Spark as a backend for my Python application.

This is how I set all things

- I have a compute engine instance on GCP. in which I have `scala-2.12.18` and `spark-3.5.0` downloaded from this source `https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0.tgz`.
- After doing untar `tar -xzvf spark-3.5.0.tgz` and moving inside `spark-3.5.0`
- I do `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Dhadoop.version=3.3.6 -DskipTests clean package` to build all necessary jar files.
- Then I started my `master` nodes on my VM's root address using `./sbin/start-master.sh --host 0.0.0.0`.
- This starts `master` node on `spark://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7077`
- `Worker` node is started using `./sbin/start-worker.sh spark://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7077`

With this above configuration, I'm able to connect to my spark application.

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "2g")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "16")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "2")
conf.setMaster("spark://xx.xx.xx.xxx:7077")
conf.setAppName("spark-app")

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
```

I run above code on my local machine. And when I check my driver configuration spark hosts the driver on my local IP address `192.168.0.102` which is why my master and worker are not able to interact with the driver because it's on my local IP and I'm not able to process anything.

I tried these two things:

- When I add `conf.set("spark.driver.host", "xx.xx.xx.xxx")` then fails to bind any random port. `java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (on a random free port)! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate binding address for the service 'sparkDriver' (for example spark.driver.bindAddress for SparkDriver) to the correct binding address.`
- `NOTE: In my GCP instance firewall rules I have allowed access on all ports "0-65535", but to save myself from unauthorized access, I also have added my public IP to the IPv4 Ranges so that I can only access the web ui` Here is how it looks, maybe the problem is here.
- [image]

When I add `conf.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")` it shows
`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Cluster deploy mode is currently not supported for python applications on standalone clusters.`

When I execute any code using this spark backend it shows error

```py
data = [1,2,3,4,5,]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
rdd.map(lambda x: x ** 2).collect()

24/02/25 14:13:46 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I tried to search about this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72365959/15531189) and I found some info then I realized that I have a driver problem because my driver is hosted locally.

Can anyone help me, with what I'm doing wrong maybe with firewall rules, and if there is another way to do this?

Please ask if something is not clear and if anyone needs more info for digging into this issue.